# Should I change the tag of a question to fit its answer?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91697/how-can-i-capture-a-rectangular-area-from-an-image) have nothing to do with tag `graphs-and-networks`.But the [nike's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91727/21532) or [mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138817/21532) make it can related with *Graph and Networks*.In such case,can I add a `graphs-and-networks` for it?

Comment: I was told that tags are for questions not answers. And even though it would be handy to tag by answer content I tend to agree we should stick to the rule.

Comment: And this is this old topic I would consider in essence a duplicate: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1033/5478 what do you think?